# Как сохранить выбранные параметры get фильтра PHP

Tags: php

Имеется фильтр, который работает корректно, но при каждом последующем применении, он перезатирает параметры предыдущего выбранного параметра. Как сделать так, чтобы при первом применении можно было отфильтровать, например возраст, затем открыть фильтр и отфильтровать только пол, но при этом, чтобы возраст оставался?

```
    <form method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">Желаемый возраст</span>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">От</span>
    <? $agefrom=$_GET['agefrom']; ?>
    <input type="number" min="18" max="99" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="agefrom" placeholder="<?=$agefrom?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="padding-right:0px;">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">До</span>
    <? $ageto=$_GET['ageto']; ?>
    <input type="number" min="18" max="99" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="ageto" placeholder="<?=$ageto?>">
    </div>
    </div>

</br>


<span class="input-group-prepend">Выберите пол</span>
<? $sex=$_GET['sex'];?>
        <? 
        if ($sex == "M") {
            $sexph = "Мужчины";
        } else if ($sex == "W") {
            $sexph = "Женщины";
        }
        if ($sex != "") {
        echo "<span class='note'></br>Выбрано: " . $sexph . "</span></br>";
        }
        ?>
        <select name="sex" class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled selected></option>
            <option value="M">Мужчины</option>
            <option value="W">Женщины</option>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отфильтровать">

</form>


// базовый запрос
$sqlbase = "login!='$login'";
$pagibase = "";

//Добавление параметров фильтра в запрос и для пагинации

if (isset($_GET['agefrom']) && $agefrom!="")  {
    $sqlbase .= "&& age>='$agefrom'";
    $pagibase .= "&agefrom=$agefrom";
}
if (isset($_GET['ageto']) && $ageto!="")  {
    $sqlbase .= "&& age<='$ageto'";
    $pagibase .= "&ageto=$ageto";
}
if (isset($_GET['sex']) && $sex!="") {
    $sqlbase .= "&& sex='$sex'";
    $pagibase .= "&sex=$sex";
}
```

Comment: При формировании HTML-формы просто у всех полей сразу выставляете значения из фильтра с предыдущей страницы.

Comment: а как это лучше сделать? Через аякс?

Comment: Да думаю просто PHP. Просто при формировании формы проверять было ли уже что-то выбрано, и если да, то заполнять поле этим выбранным значением